# How do I fix PHP Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Tags: php

How to fix

> PHP Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string
>   given in

Code :

```
$subitems_values=sanitize($_REQUEST['subitems']);
$subitems_values = array_unique($subitems_values); // error line.
$SubItemToken=implode(",", $subitems_values);
$cnt=count($subitems_values);
```

Comment: your `$subitems_values` should be an array instead of string.

Comment: $_REQUEST['subitems'] is this array?. it should be an array

Comment: can you please paste your contents for $_REQUEST['subitems'?]

Comment: refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: yes its an array Azeez

Answer (score 1):

make sure that sanitize() returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

2 posible issue

1. $_REQUEST['subitems'] is not array
2. sanitize function create string from array

Answer (score -1):

The reason why you get this errror is that the function `array_unique()` only accept an array as its first argument. So first check the datatype of **$subitems_values** using `gettype()` function .
Then try again.

```
$subitems_values=explode(',',$_REQUEST['subitems']);
if(is_array($subitems_value)){
  $subitems_values = array_unique($subitems_values); // error line.
  $SubItemToken=implode(",", $subitems_values);
  $cnt=count($subitems_values);
}
```

Comment: @karthi What is the output of $_REQUEST['subitems'].Can you show an example?

Comment: @karthi if $_REQUEST['subitems'] is a string like "abc,bcd,vbg" first you should explode the string .Then apply the result to array_unique() please try my updated answer

Comment: Gettype -> array 
Array
{
[0]=>21688
}